# Rails two scopes on has many through returns a bigger count than one single scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, associations, has-many-through

There's a Customer class with the following associations and scopes:

```
 has_many :hangouts
 has_many :bookings, through: :hangouts
 scope :already_finished, -> { joins(:bookings).where("bookings.time < ?", DateTime.now) }
 scope :who_booked_trips, -> { where(won_deal: true) }
```

When I run

```
Customer.who_booked_trips.count
```

I get the number 653

When I run

```
Customer.already_finished.count
```

I get the number 662

When I run

```
Customer.who_booked_trips.already_finished.count
```

I get the number 661!

Should not the who_booked_trips.already_finished.count be smaller than who_booked_trips.count ?

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `joins` will result in duplicate customers being returned. Take this simple example where you have 1 customer who has 2 bookings:

```
> Customer.count
=> 1
> Customer.joins(:bookings).count
=> 2
> Customer.joins(:bookings).distinct.count
=> 1
```

If you only want to return unique customers, call the `distinct` method on the scope:

```
 scope :already_finished, -> { joins(:bookings).where("bookings.time < ?", DateTime.now).distinct }
```

Answer (score 0):

Append `.uniq`

```
scope :already_finished, -> { joins(:bookings).where("bookings.time < ?", DateTime.now).uniq }
```

That should return all uniq records.

Comment: Accepted the other answer because "Rails 5.1 has removed the uniq method from Activerecord Relation and added distinct method"